# Find by nested document values with random keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection structure:

```
{
   _id : ObjectId('...'),
   randomKeysSubdocument : {
       'jhaksdf' : 'something',
       'jio348akgqug' : 'something else',
       'kgowe98akjg' : 'more things',
   }
}
```

where randomKeysSubdocument is a subdocument with random keys generated programmatically (and i don't know their names).
Is there a way how I can query by randomKeysSubdocument values in the same way as I would query them if randomKeysSubdocument were an array:

```
{
   _id : ObjectId('...'),
   randomKeysSubdocument : [
       'something',
       'something else',
       'more things',
   ]
}
```

Query:

```
db.my_collection.find({
    randomKeysSubdocument : 'something'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it should be clear that you should not do this. Structuring documents with different key names is not a good pattern, and certainly does not work well with MongoDB or general database searching.

Only "data" can be indexed, so a better structure for you would be:

```js
{
   randomKeysSubdocument : [
       { "key": 'jhaksdf', "data": 'something' },
       { "key": 'jio348akgqug', "data": 'something else' }
       { "key": 'kgowe98akjg', "data": 'more things' }
   ]
}
```

Where searching in the array as you note is already easy:

```js
db.collection.find({ "randomKeysSubdocument.data": "something" })
```

And of course that can use an index to make things faster.

---

The way you currently have things you have to rely on JavaScript processing of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) for the match and cannot use an index for this:

```js
db.collection.find(function() {
    var doc = this.randomKeysSubDocument;
    return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
       return doc[key] == "something";
    });
})
```

Which is going to be much slower than a standard query and must test every document in the collection.

For mine, I would change the structure and move away from the pattern of using "data" as the names of keys, but put it in data instead where it belongs and keeps structures consistent for searching.

Comment: I don't like the structure either, but I have to work with what I have. And probably I'll really have to change the schema, but it will influence the application code in a lot of places, that's why I wanted to find a way to query it as it is. Thanks in any way for the answer.

Comment: @kos The best approach is to "show your boss" the responses when you reach out to the community and they say "this is wrong and causes problems" then you have some backup to fix things properly. Creating code with performance problems likely leads to more work required to fix it. But if you wrote the poorly performing code then why should you get the contract to "fix" things? That's just a bit of philosophy here.

Comment: My boss doesn't mind me to refactor the code, it's me who wants to avoid it :) Seems like no way to avoid it